# ERPNEXT not create link list in non english languages

Tags: erpnext, frappe

In General Ledger Report, column Voucher Number does not have a link in some non-English languages.
I expect that the click feature is enabled on the link fields such as "Voucher Number" like in English.
My ERPNEXT and FRAPPE versions is 15.0